# How do I build a charging station for 12 iPads?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, charging

I need to charge, overnight, about 12 ipads in 1 location. Are there pre-made charging stations? Should I just buy a [surge protector](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JE9LD4) with a ton of plugs? Do you have any other idea or advice?

I wanted to have a single computer to synchronize all the iPads. Will I have to synchronize them individually? If not, how many iPods can be synchronized at the same time?

I have 12 iPads I need to charge and synchronize. How can I do this efficiently and attractively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Datamation](http://www.ipadcart.info/) offers a multi-charge/sync setup now, and apparently [Parat solutions](http://www.paratsolutions.com/parasync.html) has one in the works.

If you're looking to build your own, the Datamation unit uses a [Cambrionix C3 board](http://www.cambrionix.com/cambrionix-products/C3-CaseiPadiPodAmazonKindleNintendoDSSonyPSPchargeandsynccomponentfromCambrionix..htm) with 16 USB ports for charging and syncing. You could integrate it into your own solution.

You could also just get a 12+ port USB charger, however charging and syncing may take significantly longer this way. The Datamation site has some [charge/sync time tech specs](http://www.ipadcarts.com/tech_specs.htm) that support this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This certainly gets me well on my way to finding my solution.